# Node.js scraping brings back weird results with thepiratebay

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am building a simple Node.js server for my web scraping needs. The thing is, when I try to load The Pirate Bay, the result looks like this:

> ��[{s�6�;��nz��%Y�����G����b��N����"h�����o�$R-{s�Nj������<~u������yb����q09���&v�/�w<##��'���q}��t  *|�?g��g�E��Sg��%|M�L>8�9��+t�4� ��U���y�Ł�N}J�Tܳ(�EN9nh0C����\�������8���  �@q]��n��.�C���^dMYHg�4Ó�(��P 脱�O�R����8�0]|�J����K���M�_�_ߜ�y:��������|=��|u īz�7:F�@���wݪz|La2���p��`ȋ�����Н��y= �%k�^t��*�;\���6��Uď��_���l��r�� ��{��m�!vt豀�T��ۄ���hm��j���|��/a;�V}#��W�Z����lc_�HmȎ�!3���䠾�i����usp�)�������j_n=�l����%X�Ā ��������>����-= [PJc�v�V�ز]�X݅Ǎ0�*o��*|<"��+!8�_>%`A�G�I�e/ �s�ҝ

But much longer. I tried setting the meta charset to UTF-8 but it didn't work. Here is the main part of app.js:

```
app.get('/:key/:url', function(req, res) {
     // to prevent a bunch of people from overloading my server
     var key = req.params.key;
     if (key != '12345')
         res.send('error: incorrect key');

     else {
         // scraping itself

         // slashes confuse the system
         var url = ('http://' + req.params.url).replace('#', '/');
         // res.send('Successful');

         request(url, function(err, response, html) {
          // if no error occurred   
          if (!err) 
            res.render('index', { output: html });
          else
            res.send('error loading website');
        });
    }
});
```

There are no errors in the command line. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly looks like encoding problem.

My suggestion is to firstly load the site in your browser (if you can't, use a proxy addon, there are plenty) and investigate inside of a browser to identify what encoding is used on the site. Very likely UTF-8, but better verify.

Then it is a question of why decoding in javascript did not work, rather than *it did not work, thus there is somethign else*.

You could also on your server use simple shell tool like `wget url` to see whether it is an issue in your node.js code or in network communication between your server and site.

Here is an example of using encoding against sites with iconv module:

```
request({url: url, encoding: 'binary'}, function(error, response, html) {
    enc = charset(response.headers, html);
    if (!enc) {
        enc = jchardet.detect(html).encoding.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (enc != 'utf-8') {
        iconv = new Iconv(enc, 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE')
        html = iconv.convert(new Buffer(html, 'binary')).toString('utf-8')
    }
    console.log(html); // For debugging
});
```

---

Also, I feel like you are tryign to make a proxy server? Presuming you, like me, live in UK and the site is banned by Her Majesty. :) Clever guy.

There are far better ways to build a proxy server, your method will have issues with loading supplementary resources (javascript, images, css).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I checked, and The Pirate Bay actually uses UTF-8, so it still doesn't work. And I am not trying to create a proxy :). Although, now that you bring it up, it's actually a pretty smart move.

Comment: do console.log(html); before res.render, to verify that it does not get 'corrupted' on the way from a server to your browser.

Comment: Same thing on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem now for days. There are a couple of things I noticed:

1. Retrieving the website from Node produced the same result as retrieving it from cURL via command line.
2. Even when controlling for the encoding via passing headers, the response from the website was the same gobbledegook.

There is another way to solve the problem if you're fine with not going the pure Node route. I ended up writing a Python script to do the scraping for me and then calling it from Node using the **child_process** package (specifically the **exec** functionality). The Python file returned the content from the web page that was scraped via **sys.stdout.write** (do not use the **print** statement) so that the exec function could pick it up.

I hope that helps.